# Error while trying to create xml file

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0

The following is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.IO;

namespace xml1
{
class Program
{
    Employee[] employees = new Employee[1];
    class Employee
    {
        int _id;
        string _firstName;
        string _lastName;
        int _salary;

        public Employee(int id, string firstName, string lastName, int salary)
        {
            this._id = id;
            this._firstName = firstName;
            this._lastName = lastName;
            this._salary = salary;
        }

        public int Id { get { return _id; } }
        public string FirstName { get { return _firstName; } }
        public string LastName { get { return _lastName; } }
        public int Salary { get { return _salary; } }
    }
    void CreateXML()
    {
        //XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(@"C:\Users\simonjef\Desktop\employees.xml");
        XmlDocument doc=new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load(@"C:\Users\simonjef\Desktop\Emp.xml");

      //  XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(File.Open(@"C:\Users\simonjef\Desktop\employees.xml", FileMode.Open));
        if (!File.Exists(@"C:\Users\simonjef\Desktop\Emp.xml"))
        {
            XmlTextWriter textWritter = new XmlTextWriter(@"C:\Users\simonjef\Desktop\Emp.xml", null);
            textWritter.WriteStartDocument();
            textWritter.WriteStartElement("Employees");
            textWritter.WriteEndElement();
            textWritter.WriteEndDocument();
            textWritter.Close();
        }

        using (XmlWriter writer = doc.DocumentElement.CreateNavigator().AppendChild())
        {             
            writer.WriteStartDocument();
            writer.WriteStartElement("Employees9");

            foreach (Employee employee in employees)
            {
                writer.WriteStartElement("Employee");
                writer.WriteAttributeString("ID", employee.Id.ToString());
                writer.WriteAttributeString("FirstName", employee.FirstName);
                writer.WriteAttributeString("LastName", employee.LastName);
                writer.WriteAttributeString("Salary", employee.Salary.ToString());
                //writer.WriteElementString("ID", employee.Id.ToString());

                //writer.WriteElementString("FirstName", employee.FirstName);
                //writer.WriteElementString("LastName", employee.LastName);
                //writer.WriteElementString("Salary", employee.Salary.ToString());

                //writer.WriteEndElement();
                writer.WriteEndElement();
            }

            writer.WriteEndElement();
           writer.WriteEndDocument();

            doc.Save(@"C:\Users\simonjef\Desktop\Emp.xml"); 
        }
    }
    void AssignValues()
    {
        // Employee[] employees;
        employees[0] = new Employee(1, "David", "Smith", 10000);
        Array.Resize(ref employees, 2);
        employees[1] = new Employee(3, "Mark", "Drinkwater", 30000);
        Array.Resize(ref employees, 3);
        employees[2] = new Employee(4, "Norah", "Miller", 20000);
        Array.Resize(ref employees, 4);
        employees[3] = new Employee(12, "Cecil", "Walker", 120000);
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Program p = new Program();
        p.AssignValues();
        p.CreateXML();         
    }
}
}
```

I'm getting the following error:

`WriteStartDocument cannot be called on writers created with ConformanceLevel.Fragment.`

Why am I getting this error?

The following is the error details:

```
System.InvalidOperationException was unhandled
  Message=The Writer is closed or in error state.
  Source=System.Xml
  StackTrace:
       at System.Xml.XmlWellFormedWriter.AdvanceState(Token token)
       at System.Xml.XmlWellFormedWriter.WriteStartDocumentImpl(XmlStandalone standalone)
       at System.Xml.XmlWellFormedWriter.WriteStartDocument()
       at xml1.Program.CreateXML() in C:\Users\simonjef\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\xml1\xml1\Program.cs:line 54
       at xml1.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\simonjef\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\xml1\xml1\Program.cs:line 98
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean ignoreSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException:
```

I am using Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove the `writer.WriteStartDocument();` and `writer.WriteEndDocument();` from the `using` block. In that block, you are appending to an element, and you cannot start an XML document *inside* an element.

If you just want to create a new XML document, I would suggest doing this:

```
XmlDocument doc=new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml("<Employees9 />");

using (XmlWriter writer = doc.DocumentElement.CreateNavigator().AppendChild())
{
        foreach (Employee employee in employees)
        {
            writer.WriteStartElement("Employee");
            writer.WriteAttributeString("ID", employee.Id.ToString());
            writer.WriteAttributeString("FirstName", employee.FirstName);
            writer.WriteAttributeString("LastName", employee.LastName);
            writer.WriteAttributeString("Salary", employee.Salary.ToString());

            writer.WriteEndElement();
        }

        doc.Save(@"C:\Users\simonjef\Desktop\Account.xml"); 
}
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the quick reply. I removed the WriteStartDocument() and WriteEndDocument() and tried it again. it is not giving any error now. but the there is nothing in the xml file. Only the following is there in the xml file : <Employees /> . The other data is not getting appended.

Comment: Are you trying to modify an existing XML file, or just create a new one? It looks like you're loading an existing file. Is there anything in it when you run this code?

Comment: I'm creating a new xml file. The thing is that it checks if the file is present, if it is not present then it creates a xml file with just the root node. then again it loads it and adds the elements. So from the second time onwards, it is modifying the file.

Comment: Ok, but in one place, the filename you're using is Account.xml, and in the other, it's Emp.xml. What's the story there?

Comment: So sorry, that was a typo mistake. I edited it in the question. Also, I solved the issue, The doc.Save() should be used outside the using braces. Thanks for the help.